# Polytopes with equal facets

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, polytopes

My question is very simple though I was not able to find any related information.

> Is it true that if a convex polytope has [combinatorially isomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polytope#The_face_lattice) facets then it is combinatorially isomorphic to a regular polytope?

I am especially interested in dimensions $3$ and $4$. I think that it is true for dimension $3$ for some simple reason and not sure about dimension $4$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding simplicity from your comment onto your task, then you'll have both: alike (d-1)-facets and alike 0-facets (vertices). This usually is called a noble polytope.

Even with the additional restriction to all unit edges, regular polygonic faces, etc. this small non-exhaustive [listing](https://bendwavy.org/klitzing/explain/noble.htm) shows that not all 4D noble polytopes are regular.

--- rk

Comment: That is great! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not true. Any bipyramid (in any dimension) over a regular polytope has this property, but generally isn't regular itself. So that gives you infinitely many examples in dimension 3; the $n$-gonal bipyramids have triangles for all their facets, but aren't regular for $n=3$ or $n > 4$.

You also have the 13 [Catalan solids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_solid), or the infinite series of [trapezohedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezohedron).

Similarly, any [simplicial polytopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_polytope) have all their facets isomorphic, but aren't combinatorially regular.

This property is known as being combinatorially [isotopic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopic_figure), or facet-transitive. (Actually, that's a stronger property: not only are all the facets isomorphic, but the polytope's own automorphisms carry each facet onto any other.)

Comment: I greatly appreciate your answer. That was a mistake of mine not to mention that I am primarly interested in _simple_ polytopes with described property. Could you please provide some information in dimension 4?

Answer (score 0):

The smallest counterexample that comes to my mind is the [rhombic dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombic_dodecahedron).

[image]